# Trying to pull single product into lightbox, but rails pulling multiple/incorrect products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css, coffeescript

I have a product page listing each product of a certain group and instead of going to the product show page for each individual product when you click the main image, I would like to load the image into a css3 lightbox.

My code for _product.html.erb is the following:

```
<% if products.any? %>
<ul id="products" class="inline product-listing" data-hook>
  <% products.each do |product| %>
    <% if product.on_display? %>
      <div class="grid_1">
      <li id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="columns product three <%= cycle("alpha", "secondary", "", "omega secondary", :name => "classes") %>" data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="main-image" type="button" value="Zoom In Modal Window" class="popup_button" data-type="zoomin" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">
      <%= large_image(product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "product-image", :class => "popup_button") %>
    </div><!-- main-image-->
    **<div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="product-container zoomin">
        <span class="close">X</span>
        <%= product %>
        <%= large_image(product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "product-image") %>
    </div><!-- window-container zoomin -->
    </div><!-- overlay-container -->**
    <div class="prod_info_box">
    <%= link_to truncate(product.name, :length => 50), product, :class => 'info', :itemprop => "name", :title => product.name %>
    <span class="price selling" itemprop="price"><%= product.price_in(current_currency).display_price %></span>
```

The lightbox code is in bold. I'm using the same 'product' variable used in the main-image div to pull in the selected single product to the lightbox, but when I use it here, it seems to be pulling in several products and layering them on top of one another. And its not even pulling the correct product object. You click "The Temptress" and it pulls up "The Tim", which is the product at the very bottom right of the grid. Any idea why its doing this since I'm using the same 'product' from

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
```

Thanks for your help!

P.S. Here's the coffeescript:

```
$(document).ready ->
 $(".popup_button").click ->
  type = $(this).attr("data-type")
  $(".overlay-container").fadeIn ->
    window.setTimeout (->
      $(".product-container." + type).addClass "product-container-visible"
    ), 100


$(".close").click ->
  $(".overlay-container").fadeOut().end().find(".product-container").removeClass "product-container-visible"
```

Comment: It looks like for each product you are creating a new lightbox and then in your coffeescript, you are making them all visible because they all have the class .product-container. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Rebitzele Thank you, I believe you're right. Any idea how to make the coffeescript click function zer in on a single product? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a product id to the  using an id (or data attribute if you prefer). So you can do something like:

```
<div id="<%= product.id %>" class="product-container zoomin">
```

Then, in your coffeescript, you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready ->
 $(".popup_button").click ->
  type = $(this).attr("data-type")

  product_id = $(this).attr("data-productid")

  $(".overlay-container").fadeIn ->

    window.setTimeout (->
      $("#" + product_id + ".product-container." + type).addClass "product-container-visible"
   ), 100
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working. I tried what you have, then i tried this: 

`$(document).ready ->
  $(".popup_button").click ->
    type = $(this).attr("data-type")
    product_id = $('.product-container').attr("data-productid")
    $(".overlay-container").fadeIn ->
      window.setTimeout (->
        $(product_id + type).addClass "product-container-visible"
      ), 100`

Along with this html:

`<div class="overlay-container">
       <div class="product-container zoomin" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">`

Comment: Here's a link if that helps. http://pants.telegraphbranding.com/t/women/long-sleeve

Comment: I realize I was missing a + from my code (in product_id + ".product-container.") I just edited my code to include it. Does that help? What happens when you use my code?